# Extract value form list of tuples python

Tags: python, tuples

My list message looks as below :

```
msg = [('_SIZE', b'\\100'), ('_MODE', b'\\x00'), ('_EXPIRY', b'\\x1000')]
```

I want to extract value of _EXPIRY from this

Tried msg['_EXPIRY'], msg[0]['EXPIRY'] . What is the correct way to get the data

Comment: msg[2][1]....????

Comment: ... but what exactly does "looks as below" mean? Is it always the exact same structure, same tuples in the same order?

Comment: if you are not sure about the index then try `dict(msg)['_EXPIRY']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the approach:

```
msg_list = [('_SIZE', b'\\100'), ('_MODE', b'\\x00'), ('_EXPIRY', b'\\x1000')]
for msg in msg_list:
    if (msg[0] == "_EXPIRY"):
        print (msg[1])
        break
```

Another approach can be to convert it into `dict` and access the key as below:

```
msg_list = [('_SIZE', b'\\100'), ('_MODE', b'\\x00'), ('_EXPIRY', b'\\x1000')]
try:
    msg_dict = dict(msg_list)
    print(msg_dict['_EXPIRY'])
except KeyError as ex:
    print (f"Entry for _EXPIRY does not exists")
```

Answer (score 6):

You probably want to access **_EXPIRY** but that needs to be cast as `dict` first before accessing. OR read it by index of list of tuple `print(msg[2][1])`

```
msg = [('_SIZE', b'\\100'), ('_MODE', b'\\x00'), ('_EXPIRY', b'\\x1000')]
msg_dict = dict(msg)
print(msg_dict['_EXPIRY'])
```